# Why is XML store not available in iOS?

Tags: ios, core-data, xml-serialization

From the Core Data Programming Guide:

> **iOS**: The XML store is not available on iOS.

Why isn't this available? Is it because of the lack of certain XML classes or does it require too much processing power or RAM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple would be the authoritative source for this, so we can only guess.

It’s probably because of two factors: XML stores are slower (as stated in the [official documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPersistentStores.html), mainly because of the need to parse XML and lack of efficient algorithm/data structures for common database operations) and potentially use more disk space than SQLite stores (since data must be enclosed in tags and XML stores use human-readable representation of data).

**Edit:** libxml2 is available on iOS so XML parsing functionality (or lack thereof) is certainly not the reason.

Comment: "XML stores use human-readable representation of data" Not always. Apple could have stored data in an arbitrary XML structure, containing binary data, without caring if humans could read it easily (the corresponding MIME type would be `application/xml`). That said, I agree with the rest of your points.

Comment: @BoltClock Apple could have but IIRC they don’t. One of the reasons they give for having an XML store (on Mac OS) is that the store is human-readable, hence useful for debugging.